# My buttons wont enter into my input field Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Im trying to make a simple calculator from a youtube video. everytime i push one of the generated buttons the code will do nothing. I also got not error in my console. it just doesnt work at all

this code is in my calculator.components.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, '.', '+', '-', '*', '/', '=','CLEAR'];
val = ''
  constructor() { }

calc($event) {
  console.log("hi");

  var button = $event.srcElement.innerText;
  if (button === '='){
    this.val = eval(this.val);
  }else if ( button === 'CLEAR'){
    this.val = ''
  }else {
    console.log();
    this.val += button;
  }
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And the following code is in my calculator.component.html:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="val" type="text">
<div>
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons">{{button}}</button>
</div>
```

screenshot of the htmlpage
[image: This is an screenshot of my HTML code on my page]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `(click)` in your button to run your `calc()` function

**Template**

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons"
        (click)="$event">{{button}}</button>
```

or you can also implement it like this:

**Template**

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons"
        (click)="button">{{button}}</button>      // Passing your button name on click event
```

**Component**

```
calc(buttonName) {
  console.log("hi");

  if (buttonName === '='){
    this.val = eval(this.val);
  } else if (buttonName === 'CLEAR'){
    this.val = ''
  } else {
    console.log();
    this.val += button;
  }
}

________________________________________________________

// You can enhance the above code to:
calc(buttonName) {
  console.log("hi");

  this.val = buttonName === '='
    ? eval(this.val)
    : buttonName === 'CLEAR'
    ? ''
    : this.val += button;
}
```